# How to treat the edge of OSB in a piece of furniture

Tags: furniture, cutting

There are lots of nice pictures on the internet of untreated OSB CNC-cut into chairs/tables/benches.

What can be done to the edge of the cut to have a clean surface with no strands and splinters? Other than gluing PVC edge banding (which ruins raw aesthetics and is often unpractical for non-linear cuts)

Comment: Can you share some photos? I've never seen furniture made of it mainly because it's a terrible material for furniture.

Comment: Some of it is plywood, but the first pictures display OSB chairs https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=osb+cnc+furniture&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch#imgrc=_

Comment: I sense a lot of splinters in those households! :) That said, the one thing all those images have in common is that it appears most (if not all) of the pieces were formed from CNC routers. So I'd start there by suggesting that the first step in getting the cleanest edges as possible is to use a router to cut the pieces out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd tend to fall in the "OSB furniture sounds like a terrible idea" camp, but anyway...

Two steps come to mind - one is to seal the cut edges thoroughly using either a thin epoxy or a varnish/polyurethane type of product, to both bind small slivers and prevent or at least slow moisture intake and resultant edge swelling. The other is to sand the edges (you want to seal first, then sand so that sanding doesn't turn into peeling off slivers) - and you may want to seal again after sanding.

Comment: Found this example, edge is used up to extreme. http://www.ibuildit.ca/Woodworking%20Projects/osb-stool-2.html (video https://youtu.be/ZjBf8S-zSOQ?t=361)
I wonder if sanding and oiling will hold for long.

Comment: Yeesh. For all that work (or quite possibly with a lot less work, when starting with different material), I'd far rather invest a bit in actual lumber, but - whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that OSB plus Redgard is really really a good combo.  The redgard is kind of thick and can't really be sanded so use is kind of all or none but it does have high functionality/durability and you can paint it.

Comment: I think that's an interesting option...but obviously only useful for painting, as it's colored and would leave a red finish (or hey, if one is using OSB for the industrial look, maybe a coat of redgard fits right in!) :)

Comment: Now you got me thinking about regard as a finish in general...I might have to try that at some point...

Comment: @DA01 - We always have a little redgard left over after jobs and have used it on almost anything you can think of.  It takes a second coat on wood a day after to look smooth but finishes with kind of an IKEA furniture shine.  It obviously smells like ass so that is its drawback.  Your funriture will smell for 2-3 weeks.  It is horrible the first few days.

Comment: @DA01 , Do you know what redgard is (what it consists of)? This specific product is not available here, I'll be looking for a substitute.

Comment: @Gleb - Redgard or Hydroban or any other type of liquid waterproof membrane.  Just look up either of those products to get your equivalent.  I can't imagine an area not having this available but you can order it too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a related question over in [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/). There are some great suggestions  [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/will-painting-the-edges-of-plywood-hide-the-layers).

Comment: Note that question refers to plywood--not OSB. Some similarities, of course, but really very different as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using a router with a good carbide/carbide tipped bit, preferably a spiral cut one makes incredibly nice edges on most surfaces. Some companies even make some specifically designed for OSB, Laminate, formica, and harder materials. I think a good sharp bit, running at an appropriate speed will leave you with the finish you're looking for.

Comment: IMPE, the resulting edges, as they come off the router, will cut you.